# sql71501 sql parameter has unresolved reference to build-in type

Tags: visual-studio-2012, database-project, table-valued-parameters, built-in-types

from VS2012 I created a Database project and created ad custom type

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.TypeProductCategoryTable AS TABLE
    ( ProductID int, CategoryID int )
```

Now when I write stored procedure with using this type, i get compile error

> sql71501 sql parameter has unresolved reference to build-in type

Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_ProductCategory_Mapping]
    @tvProdCat dbo.ProductCategoryTableType READONLY
AS
insert into tProductCategories(ProductId,CategoryId)
    SELECT @tvProdCat
RETURN 0
```

How to handle this? Can we create custom type on Visual studio Database project

Comment: The name is different. TypeProductCategoryTable vs. ProductCategoryTableType

Comment: I am getting same error with my database project. The problem started when I added a custom type in my Database project in VS2012 and used it in a stored procedure. Everything works fine as far as data operations are concerned, its just annoying coz' it wont let me build the database project? Any pointers or help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can use pre-deployment script in visual studio project.
for doing this you need to add 2 files in VS:
1.
create UserDefinedTableType.sql in your database project in VS and put the scrip of creating table type inside this script.
2.in your database project add UserScripts -> pre-Deployment script and call the script in the step 1 here . using this code :
:r .\Scripts\Pre-Deployment\UserDefinedTableType.sql

the unresolved reference will be resolved with this solution

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and realized that somehow the build node for the TVP was inserted below the SP where it was used within my .sqlproj file. once I moved the TVP above the SP I no longer received the error in VS and the project deployed as expected with no errors.
I had not realized previously that the order of the build nodes in the .sqlproj mattered but apparently the the DACPAC Compiler wasn't built to intelligently determine the order of the build process which makes sense in retrospect. I'd rather have that control even if it did in this case trip me up.